# ¿Cómo ocultar las columnas de una tabla HTML dinámica mente con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una tabla dinámica obtenida de una función `$.ajax()` y una consulta `SQL` en `PHP` y lo que deseo es ocultar ciertas columnas para eso pense en crear un `JSON` con los indices de columna a ocultar

```
columnas ocultas =[{
                      tabla1:[0,3,5],
                      tabla2:[1,4],
                      tabla3:[0,4,7]
                  }]
```

En mi `JSON` tengo varias arreglos, ya que mediante una comparación `switch` utilizare el arreglo correspondiente para la tabla, en este caso sera el `tabla1`

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Deseo ocultar los datos que servirán de indices del elemento `ocultas.tabla1` en mi tabla html.

pensé utilizar `querySelectAll()`, en el `thead` no tengo problema para obtener el resultado deseado, pero en el `tbody`, sí, ya que al obtener `tbodyParent.querySelectAll("tr>td")`obtengo toda la colección de nodes pero sin diferenciar posiciones, es aqui donde tengo el problema para ocultar las columnas.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla es generando un CSS que aplique al número de columna por `:nth-child()`, y así las esconda.

Por ejemplo, para ocultar la columna 3, el CSS generado sería:

```
table>thead>tr>th:nth-of-type(3),
table>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(3){
    display: none;
}
```

Incluso podemos generar todo el CSS dinámicamente, concatenando el texto que oculta únicamente a las columnas que quieras.

**Código**

```js
const columnas_ocultas = {
        tabla1: [0, 3, 5],
        tabla2: [1, 4],
        tabla3: [0, 4, 7]
      },
      head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
      estilos = document.createElement('style');

head.appendChild(estilos);


function estiloTabla(tablaElegida) {
  //generar nuevo estilo a partir de tabla1/tabla2/tabla3
  let nuevoEstilo = '';

  for (let esconderColumna of tablaElegida) { //valores del array
    nuevoEstilo += 'table>thead>tr>th:nth-child(' 
      + (esconderColumna + 1)
      + '),table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(' 
      + (esconderColumna + 1)
      + ') {display: none}';//ocultar esa columna
  }

  estilos.innerHTML = nuevoEstilo;
}
```

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
td, th {border: 1px solid;}
```

```html
<h5>Elegir estilo</h5>
<!-- Como ejemplo para probar llamar a la función -->
<input type=button value="estiloTabla(columnas_ocultas.tabla1)" onclick="estiloTabla(columnas_ocultas.tabla1)"><br>
<input type=button value="estiloTabla(columnas_ocultas.tabla2)" onclick="estiloTabla(columnas_ocultas.tabla2)"><br>
<input type=button value="estiloTabla(columnas_ocultas.tabla3)" onclick="estiloTabla(columnas_ocultas.tabla3)">

<h5>Tabla</h5>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dato 1</td>
            <td>dato 2</td>
            <td>dato 3</td>
            <td>dato 4</td>
            <td>dato 5</td>
            <td>dato 6</td>
            <td>dato 7</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Serviría para la reutilizacion de código, es decir como tengo muchas tablas que hacen lo mismo, pero de diferente tamaño es por eso que deseo cargar todos los datos y ocultar ciertas columnas dependiendo de la tabla a utilizar y mi consulta sql es similar, es el mismo código para diferentes tablas

Comment: Quizás no haya quedado claro, pero este código es exactamente eso: reutilizable en cualquier cantidad de columnas, o incluso si se quiere alternar diferentes vistas (columnas que se muestran/ocultan dinámicamente) de la misma tabla